# How to Pivot data in Power BI and then show a line chart for the pivot-ed data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have interest rates curves data for different dates and i want to compare them. In excel I create a pivot and then from pivot a chart. How do I the same in power bi?

data example:

[image]

example of data pivoted in excel (note the filter here chart comparing the series):

[image]

Example of PivotChart

[image]
I want to create this chart in Power BI

data in text format

| SeriesName | SeqId | Data | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EUROIS | 1 | 31-Dec-21 | 1.1 |
| EUROIS | 2 | 31-Dec-21 | 1.2 |
| EUROIS | 3 | 31-Dec-21 | 1.3 |
| EUROIS | 4 | 31-Dec-21 | 1.4 |
| EUROIS | 5 | 31-Dec-21 | 1.5 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 1 | 31-Dec-21 | 3.2 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 2 | 31-Dec-21 | 3.3 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 3 | 31-Dec-21 | 3.4 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 4 | 31-Dec-21 | 3.5 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 5 | 31-Dec-21 | 3.6 |
| EUROIS | 1 | 31-Jan-22 | 0.1 |
| EUROIS | 2 | 31-Jan-22 | 0.2 |
| EUROIS | 3 | 31-Jan-22 | 0.3 |
| EUROIS | 4 | 31-Jan-22 | 0.4 |
| EUROIS | 5 | 31-Jan-22 | 0.5 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 1 | 31-Jan-22 | 2.2 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 2 | 31-Jan-22 | 2.3 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 3 | 31-Jan-22 | 2.4 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 4 | 31-Jan-22 | 2.5 |
| EUREURIBOR3M | 5 | 31-Jan-22 | 2.6 |

Comment: Where did you run into problems doing this?

Comment: i did this in excel, i want to do this now in power bi (these pivot chart based on pivot table is what i want to replicate)

Comment: I know. That is what you wrote.  If you know nothing about Power BI, start with some tutorials so you can learn how to get your data into the program. That will depend on your data source.  Then you'll probably want to Pivot the date column with no aggregation and create your visual from the results. There are many tutorials on line.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ron, I am a newbie but i can get my way around including simple DAX. I created a Matrix visual corresponding to excel pivot. However, i do not know how to get pivot chart corresponding to what i have displayed above. Unfortunately, google-ing did not lead to success

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear to me where you were knowledge wise.  I suggest going into Power Query (Home=>Transform), then pivot on the Date column, with Values coming from the Value column and no aggregation.  Save that and add a Line chart visual.   You'll be able to filter it, do some formatting, etc.